# Combining records with same order id in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, customers and orders, i would like to display all orders for each customer on a page. From orders when there are 2 orders belonging to same customer id i would like combine them into 1 div so there are shown together. Do i need to create 2 queries and loops to achieve this? E.g. 1 loop to get orders and another loop inside it, check if order id is a duplicate get the record. Please advise me and give me any ideas you might have thanks in advance.

**Sample Tables**
Customer Table
Customer ID, Customer Name
1, Jason
2, Joe

**Order Table**
Order ID, Customer ID, Order Details
1, 1, Pen
2, 1, Watch
3, 2, Mirror

**What I would like to achieve:**
Customer_ID, Customer_Name, Customer_Order
1, Jason,
Pen, Watch
2, Joe,
Mirror.

Comment: Is it sufficient to `JOIN` `orders` and `users` and sort by `user`? Are you doing anything with paging?

Comment: No, as I want to combine orders for each user into 1 div, otherwise its not a problem I already achieved that. Thanks

Comment: If they're sorted you can combine them. Loop over the orders, see if the user is the same as the last, then continue printing orders, else end the div and start a new one for the next user.

Answer (score 1):

you can use join for obtain all  the info you need
eg for customer 1

```
select c.Customer_ID, c.Customer_Name, o.Customer_Order
from Customer c 
inner join Order o on o.Customer_ID = c.Customer_ID
where and  c.Customer_ID = 1
```

Comment: As im getting all orders for all users Im thinking to add a query similar to the one you shared into the while loop. Thanks